# Valid webpage displays in WebKit browsers and IE but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website at http://derek.genevievehoward.com/ will not display in Firefox, even though the HTML and CSS are valid. The body has `display:none;` in the CSS but my script should fade the body in with Javascript.

When I look at the developer tools in Firefox, it loads all the scripts, CSS, and HTML, but it seems that the fade in doesn't happen. My guess is that the Javascript isn't executing automatically when the page loads, but I have no idea why that would be.

I have tried commenting out my link to the CSS, then my links would load in the other content with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling script.js twice, I'd suggest taking the first one out of the header. You should also put your jquery functions in a  document ready function.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(this).css("display", "block");
    //Fade in
    $("body").fadeIn(2000, function () {
        notify("My page is currently being changed. Expect brokenness.");
        $("article").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    //Link fades
    $("nav a").hover(function () {$(this).fadeTo(300,1)},function () {$(this).fadeTo(300,.3)});

    //notifications
    function notify(message) {
        document.getElementById("notifyText").innerHTML = message;
        $("#notification").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(4000);
    }

    //fade new content
    function fadeLoad(newUrl) {
        $("article").fadeOut(1000,function () { 
            $("article").load(newUrl, function () { 
                $("article").fadeIn(1000);
                });
        })
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but it still didn't fix the Firefox problem. They defiantly improve my website though, so thanks!

Comment: Are you experiencing the same problem on Firefox?

Comment: Looks like the fadeIn function is messing up in firefox. It starts changing the opacity but reverts back to display:none; Check my updated answer to see if this will work.

Comment: Added $(this).css("display", "block"); in the body function

Comment: This should happen on document ready so you should still get the transition.

Comment: Argh, I'll pull up a fiddle and see what I can do.

Comment: I moved your `$(this).css("display", "block");` thing to right after `$(document).ready(function() {` AND NOW IT WORKS!!!!!!!!! WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!! Thank you sooooo much!